# List available appium session id

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android

Is there any way to list all available Appium sessions id before doing driver initialization ?

```
driver.init(desired_capability)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can check to see if there already sessions on the server by sending a request to `/wd/hub/sessions`.

For example, if your server is running on

```
0.0.0.0:4723
```

You can get the list of sessions by opening the following URL in your browser

```
http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub/sessions
```