# How to get the session id of the mobile phone?

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium-desktop

I am doing automation testing for an Android device, but there is an input box that requires filling in a session ID. I don't know how can I get a session ID of the mobile phone?

[image: screenshot]

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407055/list-available-appium-session-id  you can follow the answers mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/session/get/), you can get the session details through this (Java example):

```
driver.getSessionDetails();
```

where driver is the driver you instantiated.

Also, the sessionId is an attribute on the driver itself.

[Reference](https://appium.io/docs/en/2.0/reference/interfaces/appium_types.Driver/#sessionid)